# How to prevent the automatic switch from an email in evolution/thunderbird to firefox when clicking on a hyperlink in the email?

Tags: firefox, thunderbird, evolution, settings, window

When I click on a **hyperlink** in an email (Ubuntu 12.04, Evolution 3.2.3 or thunderbird 12, although it happened in previous versions as well), the program window (Evolution) in focus changes to Firefox (default internet browser) to open the webpage. I would like that it does **NOT** switch automatically from Evolution to Firefox with every clicked hyperlink as I would prefer to read the whole email first and then "manually" go to the Firefox with the opened webpages.

I know that it is possible to prevent this **automatic change of program window** (email client to internet browser) as in Ubuntu 11.10 I had this preferred behaviour (before I now installed Ubuntu 12.04).

Does anybody know where I can change the preferences for this issue?
Thanks for any help, it bothers me daily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid that: open config window in Firefox:

```
about:config
```

there found:

```
browser.tabs.loadDivertedInBackground
```

and change to True